# can someone help figure out this error?? (C++)

Tags: c++

Getting this error when compiling:

horserace.cpp:32:22: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
 string coinflip0(h0) {
                      ^

Here's my code (currently trying to gt the first 'horse' to run):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

string h0 = "0................";
string h1 = "1................";
string h2 = "2................";
string h3 = "3................";
string h4 = "4................";

string coinflip0(h0);
int main(){
   cout << "Press Enter to begin! " <<endl;
   cin.ignore();
   std::cout << h0 << endl;
  // bool keepgoing = true;
//      srand(time(NULL));//time goes back to zero for each loop
  // while(keepgoing){
//      for(int num=0; num<5; num++){

//      } // end for
  // } // end while

   cout << "\n Press Enter to continue " << endl;
   cin.ignore();
   cout << endl;
   string coinflip0(h0);
   cout << h0 << endl;
} // end main

string coinflip0(h0){

   int position = 0; // current position of horse

   // find random number(0 or 1)
   int num = rand() % 2;
   position = position + num;

   if(num==1){
        std::swap(h0[position], h0[position+1]);
   return string h0;
   } // end if
}//end coin flip
```

Comment: The `string coinflip0(h0);` inside of `main` is not correct syntax.  The error message is telling you which lines it's complaining about.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and then see what is a [mcve].

Comment: `string coinflip0(h0); int main()` -- What is that line of code before `int main()` supposed to do?  If it is a function *declaration*, `h0` is not a parameter type.

Comment: Please make the title more descriptive of the problem. Pretty much everything on this site is covered by "Can someone help me figure this out?" For example, you could use a title like "expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token", so that the next person with this error can find it.

Comment: `string coinflip0(h0);` is an invalid declaration I think it supposed to be`string coinflip0(string h0);`  which is like `<return_type> function_name(<data_type> <parameters>)`

Comment: `return string h0;` is also wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got multiple errors in your code. First is a syntax error - when you declare a function which takes some argument (`h0` in your case), you have to specify the argument type.
Above your main function, you say that there will be some function `coinflip0`:

```
string coinflip0(h0);
```

The function returns a `string`, but there isn't specified what type the argument `h0` is.

To do so, just write the type in front of the function argument like this:

```
string coinflip0(string h0);
```

The same applies to the function definition.

---

The second error in your code is when you `return` from the `coinflip0` function. First of all, the return type is already specified in the function signature (see above) so instead of writing...

```
return string h0;
```

... you should just write:

```
return h0;
```

And also, if the function says that it returns something (`string` in this case), it must return it under all conditions, not only if one or two conditions are met.
That means you should move the `return` statement out of the `if` branch or return something else at the end of the function.

Comment: Note that `ho` is also the name of a global scope `std::string`. The original intention may have been a misinformed attempt to "import" the global scope object into the function (though such a thing is not necessary in c++). At the very least, the local `h0` hides the global one and is likely intended to represent the same object. Since `h0` is taken by value, modifications to it won't be reflected on the global `h0` as intended. The function should either take `h0` by reference (and ideally be renamed) or the function should operate on the global `h0` (not ideal, but works).

Comment: On second though, since the function returns `h0` (or tries to), it would also work to have `main` assign the result of `coinflip0` to `h0`, though again, it's not an ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

When you are declaring a function, there are a few key things to remember.

**The return type, the function name, and the function arguments.**

Right before your main() function you have

```
string coinflip0(h0);
```

So here we can see your return type is a string, your function name is coinflip0, and the argument being passed in you have named h0, however, you forget to specify the argument type, which is likely causing your first error (usually your error message will show a line number that can direct you to what line is causing your code to not run). Instead your function should look something like this:

```
string coinflip0(string h0); // assuming you want to pass in a string
```

you can even leave your function declaration as just

```
string coinflip0(string);
```

^ without using the argument name. You will have to provide the argument name though wherever you have your function definition.

In your function definition, when you are returning a variable, you do not need to include the data type, because you specified that already in the name of your function.

So you can just write:

```
return h0;
```